# How can I release a single apk with 2 arm build support?

Tags: android, build

I have a 2 apk file with release build on ue4 but I have some problem while launching on market, first build arm64-v8a and second is armeabi-v7a, so how can I upload 2 files for launch without app bundle build and armeabi-v7a with 64? Unreal Engine cant do this so Android Studio bundle build cant build because my app after Android Studio recompile cant launch on device and file size so small UE4: 45mb AS: 20mb

> How can I release a single apk, with 2 arm build support ?

Answer (score 0):

try build with bundles. go to build menu click -> Build bundle apk -> Build bundles.

Comment: yes i did like that, opening ...\Intermediate\Android\APK\gradle and do Bundles build, my bundles 25mb with optimize and installed correct but then launching my app just close